# jQuery UI - positioning a hidden div using position API does not position correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to position a div using jquery UI [position](http://jqueryui.com/position/) API (`#changer` relative to `.demo`) in below HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/jttdk/1/

```
<div class="demo-content">
    <div class="demo" title="click anywhere inside" >demo div</div>
    <div class="demo" title="click anywhere inside" >demo div</div>
    <div class="demo" title="click anywhere inside" >demo div</div>
    <div class="demo" title="click anywhere inside" >demo div</div>
</div>
<div id="changer">changer div</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.demo').click(function() {
    var _that = this;
    $("#changer").fadeOut(100, function() {
        console.log(_that.className);
        $(this).position({
            of: _that,
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'right top',
            offset: '10 10'
        }).show();
    });

});
```

**Note:**

1. It works fine the first time.
2. The same works fine if I remove `.fadeOut` and move the `.position` code outside like below

http://jsfiddle.net/jttdk/3/

```
    $("#changer").position({
        of: this,
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'right top',
        offset: '10 10'
    }).show();
```

Same fails if I add a `.hide` before `.position`. ((i.e) `$("#changer").hide().position`)

I am curious to know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Does this help? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jttdk/4/)

Comment: @JamesKleeh Thank you.. Yes it does.. but was wondering why `.position` was messing it up..

Comment: I'm not familiar with the position API, but from a glance, it seems like it has to be a child element for it to work correctly.

Comment: That doesn't explain why removing the fadeout fixes it.

Comment: @JamesKleeh mm no.. doesn't help http://jsfiddle.net/jttdk/5/

Comment: @Vega Please see my answer below, you can't use `.position()` on hidden elements.

Comment: **[This is the similar to this question.][1]**

Click above link.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647468/positioning-the-element-second-time-using-jquery-uis-position-does-not-work-as/27042704#27042704

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [jQuery UI Position documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) states "*Note: jQuery UI does not support positioning hidden elements.*" So, by fading the element out first you prevent `.position()` from working correctly. Since `.fadeOut()` applies `display: none;` to the element it has no location and hence cannot be moved relatively.

You can, however, use `.animate()` to only change the opacity:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/jttdk/6/

jQuery:

```
$('.demo').click(function() {
    var _that = this;
    $("#changer").animate({
        "opacity": 0
    }, 100, function() {
        $(this).position({
            of: _that,
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'right top',
            offset: '10 10'
        }).animate({
            "opacity": 1
        }, 100)
    });
});​
```

Note that I removed `display: none;` from the CSS.

Comment: mm makes sense.. Thanks, I just started to digging jquery code :)

Comment: Just hit the 200 rep/day limit for the first time cause of this `:D`

Comment: You deserve it. I spent at least 20 min trying to solve this one when he posted it. Sometimes you just need to read the whole doc instead of trying to code your way out! :)

Answer (score 3):

Flip the order of `.position(...)` and `.show()` -- jQuery UI `position` plugin cannot calculate location correctly for hidden elements.

```
$('.settings-icon').click(function(){
  $('#control-panel').show().position({
    of: $(this),
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left top'
   });
});
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice.

Comment: @G.Samaras explanation added ;)

Comment: @drzaus I would expect the original author to add it, not you (no that I have something with you...but it's his answer! :O ;) ).