# Positioning the element second time using JQuery UI's position does not work as expcted

Tags: jquery, positioning

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ya3w7/2/

HTML:

```
<img src="http://cdn.tacky.me/m/static/settings16.png" class="settings-icon"/>

<div id="control-panel">
    <img src="http://cdn.tacky.me/m/static/settings16.png" />
    <a href="#" style="float:right" id="close-cp">X</a>
    <div class="link_container"><a href="#">Show Profile</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.settings-icon 
{
    margin: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#control-panel
{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: none;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.settings-icon').click(function(){
    $('#control-panel').position({
        of: $('.settings-icon'),
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'left top'
    });
    $('#control-panel').show();
});

$('#close-cp').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#control-panel').hide();
});
```

**What I am trying to do:**
I have a settings image, upon clicking which it positions an absolutely positioned div (called contgrol-panel) around this img.

**What I am seeing:**

First time I click on the img it works fine

I dismiss the control panel by clicking on X on the top right corner

Second time I click the control panel shows up somewhere else

**How to Repro**

Go to the fiddle

- Click on the settings icon for the first time
- Dismiss the control panel which drops down by clicking on the X
- Click on the settings icon once again
- See control panel popping up somewhere else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to put the control panel back to 0, 0 after it's closed. Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ya3w7/3/.

```
$('.settings-icon').click(function(){
    $('#control-panel').position({
        of: $(this),
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'left top'
    });
    $('#control-panel').show();
});

$('#close-cp').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#control-panel').css({top: '0px', left: '0px'}).hide();
});
```

Comment: thats a good idea ... however it will not handle the situation where I have multiple settings icons scattered on the page and want to show the control panel around those ... for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya3w7/2/

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you would have multiple icons, I updated the example and the fiddle with something that should work.

Comment: awesome!! ... works ... just curious though ... why do I need to reset the top and left for my control-panel div ...

Comment: Because the position method is setting the left & top of the control-panel at an offset that is relative to it's current left & top, so if you don't clear it, it will keep moving down and to the right at increments of control-panel.width & control-panel.height.

Answer (score 0):

**because jquery ui doesn't support position to hidden element, you have to show and position.**

```
$('.settings-icon').click(function(){
  $('#control-panel').show().position({
    of: $(this),
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left top'
   });
});
```