# JQuery UI Position is different if executed on same element more than once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

I am using the JQuery UI position function to move a div out of hidding and into another div on the screen. This works.

```
$("#b"+num).position({
    my: 'left top',
    at: parent.data('pos'),//parent is set dynamicaly $('#some_div')
    of: parent,
    collision: 'none'
}).show('fast');
```

I have another button that hides the positioned div And yet another button to bring it back. When it is brought back the position function is run again with the same parameters. however the new position is in a different spot.

I suspect this is because the div is moving relative to its original position which changes on the first run through. Is there a way to reset the div when I hide it so that it goes back to the original position?

Comment: Try to run the position function after you make the element visible (e.g. call show and then the position).

Comment: That did the trick, although I don't know why.. Can you put that as an answer so I can give you credit? Thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the position function after you make the element visible (e.g. call show and then the position)

See [jQuery UI - positioning a hidden div using position API does not position correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901528/jquery-ui-positioning-a-hidden-div-using-position-api-does-not-position-correc)